# In react how to set initial state when I clicked that route again

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react, react-route.

I have sidebar in which I have several page links, suppose I am on one page and on that I have two things - form and grid, when I open that page, grid comes when I click on add button, I set state as false. So my form opens, now I click on the same page from sidebar then I want to show grid instead of form.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions

Comment: give a new key to your route everytime it is clicked, it will remount the component

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, Yes sure, I will .. thanks for your suggetion :-)

Comment: I post my answer, d@ShubhamKhatri,,, how to give that ? and does it correct way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.push({
  pathname: '/users',
  state:{iSGrid:true}
})
componetWillRecieveProps(){
 this.setState({
 isGrid : this.props.location.state.isGrid 
});
```

Comment: Please, extend your answer.